# sed - how do I make this a "one liner"?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, bin

I would like for this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat source.txt | sed "/replace_text_holder/ {
r file.txt
d
}" | cat
```

do be written like **this**:

```
cat source.txt | sed "/replace_text_holder/ { r file.txt d }" | cat
```

but that doesn't work. Anyone know why, and/or how I fix it?

I'm currently being harassed by this error:

```
unbalanced "{"
```

I've tried inserting "\n" to make it believe there's a new line, but that doesn't work.

Clearly I have no idea what I'm doing...

Comment: I don't think you need the 'cat's, btw. sed < source.txt should redirect in. What's the final cat doing ?

Comment: This is just a test script. Sure I could use "<" for input, but that's not what's the problem here (I think). I guess the problem lies with the curly bracers who for some unapparent reason needs to be on their own lines... Further down the line I need a one liner to use in a make file. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/replace_text_holder/{r file.txt' -e 'd}'
```

Comment: Yay (and there was much rejoicing)! This worked like a charm! :) Thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: If your `sed` doesn't like multiple `-e` arguments, you can probably join the script fragments with semicolons or newlines, like `sed '/replace_text_holder/{r file.txt;d}' source.txt`

Comment: But shouldn't semicolon work here? I'm surprised that it doesn't.

Comment: @Thor - I struggled with that for a few minutes, and by the time I gave up, kev had already posted his (correct) answer.  Sigh.  I'd love to know why that doesn't work.

Comment: The semi-colon does not work because it is treated as part of the filename to the `r` command.